# OLED not updating display

Tags: gps, display, tinygps

I'm trying to connect a GPS unit (GY-GPS6MV2) and an OLED screen as in the diagram below (green connector is GPS; VCC, RX, TX, GND left to right):

[image]

Here's the code I've come up with:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_SH1106.h>
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define OLED_RESET 4
Adafruit_SH1106 display(OLED_RESET);
static const int RXPin = 5, TXPin = 3;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;
float vkph;
float vmps;

TinyGPSPlus gps;
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);
  display.begin(SH1106_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
  display.display();
  delay(2000);
  display.clearDisplay();
}

void loop(){
  while (ss.available() > 0){
    gps.encode(ss.read());
    vkph = gps.speed.kmph();
    vmps = gps.speed.mps();
    if (gps.location.isUpdated()){
      Serial.print("Position: "); 
      Serial.print(gps.location.lat(), 6);
      Serial.print(" : "); 
      Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), 6);
      Serial.print("Speed: ");
      Serial.print(vmps); 
      Serial.print(" m/s");
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.print(vkph);
      Serial.println( " km/hr"); 
      
      display.clearDisplay();
      display.setTextSize(2);
      display.setTextColor(WHITE);
      display.setCursor(0,0);
      display.println("Hello"); // Changing this to display.println(vmps);
      display.setTextSize(2);
      display.setTextColor(WHITE);
      display.println("World"); // Changing this to display.println(vkph);
      display.display();
      delay(1000); 

    }
  }
}
```

The GPS outputs to the serial monitor fine, and the screen displays "Hello `\n` World" as expected. But when I make the changes indicated in the comments to the display part of the code, the display just shows its splash screen, flashing when the GPS updates.

How can I get the display to show the speeds in m/s and km/hr?

Answer (score -1):

> Maybe you need to add `delay()` in your code,I am not sure.

```
display.clearDisplay();
      display.setTextSize(2);
      display.setTextColor(WHITE);
      display.setCursor(0,0);
      display.println("Hello"); // Changing this to display.println(vmps);
      display.setTextSize(2);
      display.setTextColor(WHITE);
      display.println("World"); // Changing this to display.println(vkph);
      display.display();
      delay(1000);
```

Comment: Why, and where?

Comment: Because OLED doesn't have a time to keep showing.

Comment: Is this an answer or a question? Also please elaborate more, so that the answer is really helpful

Comment: I tried this, even before you posted the edit. Same problem, only now it takes 1000 milliseconds to flash the splash screen.

Comment: Have you also added the delay after the GPS display code?